# iconv not working when dynamic variable is used

Tags: php, iconv

I am using following code to convert spanish characters to normal English characters:

```
function test_enc($text)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf8');
    return iconv('utf8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', $text);
}
echo test_enc('TéstFirst'); returns TestFirst
```

and it is working fine, but when I am passing this argument dynamically from other array having same value then it is returning nothing like:

```
echo test_enc($data['firstname']);
```

I have used var_dump to see the difference and it returned following:

```
var_dump('TéstFirst');//returned string(10) "TÃ©stFirst"
var_dump($data['travelername']);// returned string(9) "TéstFirst"
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is the PHP Script File also set to `utf8` in your Tool (like Netbeans, PHPStorm)?

Comment: no I haven't set anything like that in my file.

Comment: What do you use? PHPStorm? And not `in my file` its a general setting how to pasre an php-script (keep in mind that you can also paste HTML plain text in a phpscript after closing tag ?>)

Comment: no I am using geany.

Comment: I have added header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8'); line on top but that also didn't make it worked.

Comment: Try `/* geany_encoding=UTF-8 */` see: http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#character-sets-and-unicode-byte-order-mark-bom

Comment: Also if you are using geany not under command line, check your window and look for `encoding: UTF8` at the bottom of the window. If there is not `UTF8` you have too change this

Comment: Look here: http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#files-preferences   there you can change the `default encoding`

Comment: its already utf8 set in geany.

Comment: mmmh then `var_dump('TéstFirst');` should work correct. The problem is else where located, `passing this argument dynamically` have you read the first answer? did the data came from db?

Comment: Its from API, not from db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the output you provided from `var_dump(bin2hex($data['firstname']))` which is `string(18) "54e973744669727374"`, this string is not valid UTF-8. As such if you try to convert it *from* utf8 to anything else in `iconv` it will give you an error telling you it's not valid utf8 and return `false`.

```
var_dump(iconv('utf8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', hex2bin("54e973744669727374")));
```

This gives you

```
PHP Notice:  iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in ... on line ...
bool(false)
```

What we *could* try to do is first attempt to convert this string into valid UTF-8 and then use `iconv` `TRANSLIT`. Right now we're just telling `iconv` that it's already valid utf8, which it's clearly not.

```
var_dump(utf8_encode(hex2bin("54e973744669727374"))); //string(10) "TéstFirst"

//string(9) "TestFirst"
var_dump(iconv('utf8', 'ascii//TRANSLIT', utf8_encode(hex2bin("54e973744669727374"))));
```

It might be better to just consult the documentation for the API you're using and figure out what character encoding they are sending the data in to safely convert from that to utf8.

Comment: I am getting my data from API in array form not from db, after using header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); response is: string(10) "TéstFirst" for var_dump('TéstFirst'); and string(9) "T�stFirst" for var_dump($data['firstname']); and still no result in test_enc($data['firstname']);

Comment: `"T�stFirst"` is __clearly__ not valid UTF-8. It's likely your data is getting corrupted somewhere along the way between your PHP and your browser. The best thing to do is use `var_dump(bin2hex($data['firstname']))` and share that as it will serialize the string for safe transfer over HTTP.

Comment: response of var_dump(bin2hex($data['firstname'])); is string(18) "54e973744669727374"

Comment: Well, that's not UTF-8. Whatever API is sending you that data isn't sending you valid UTF-8. Notice `iconv` will give you an error when you run that string through as UTF-8 ***`iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string`***

Comment: Is there a way to convert the data into valid UTF-8 as we cannot change the data format within API?

Comment: Well, you could _try_ to encode it as utf8, but that may or may not give you the desired result. What you're trying to do here is tell `iconv` I want to conver this string (_which I believe to be valid utf8_) into ASCII. But the string isn't valid utf8 and attempting to convert to utf8 may or may not result in meaningful output. You may very well corrupt the string upon doing so, because it might have any valid utf8 representation. You might be better off just figuring out what characterset encoding the API **does** use and convert from that into utf8 instead.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include this new information.

Comment: mb_detect_encoding($data['firstname'], 'auto'); is giving "UTF-8" as output.

Comment: Don't rely on `mb_detect_encoding`. It's a pretty broken implementation. I'm telling you outright ***that is not valid utf8***.

Comment: Actually there is no way to get characterset of API, so I will need to convert their data to valid UTF8 (as you have said it is invalid), otherwise I will not be able to save data that they are sending.

Comment: Not sure why you believe there is no way for you to get the characterset the API is sending data in. Just ask the people that maintain that API or look at their documentation. Did you even try that? It's the safest way to ensure your encoding is handled properly. Otherwise, my answer addresses how you could _try_ to convert it to utf-8.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was getting data from nusoap library of which request was in ISO-8859-1, I changed it to "UTF-8" and then used utf_encode() in case string is not in utf 8 format. This worked sucessfully. Thanks again :).